# prometheus data scrape is at 30s internal but the data in grafana is coming in 2 mins intervals

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-operator

I have a prometheus operator setup which in a kuberntes cluster.
The scrape interval is set to 30s but the data coming in grafana is coming in 2mins intervals?

there is a VPN connection between grafana and prometheus so there is a delay as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution
This was on grafana end
I was using some pre made dashboard which had the min internal set to 1 min
I changed it to the default 15s

[image]